# Insert entire row values selected from MySql populated drop down list into another MySql Table

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have spent hours on this problem!

In short... I have a table called "customer_list" this table has 4 fields (ID, NAME, IDCUST and LIST_REF), at the moment i am able to join "IDCUST" and "NAME" together to shown in my drop down list with a hyphen like so: IDCUST - NAME. And then gets inserted into the second table called "customer_reference" perfectly!

However i ve spent the last 2 days trying to get the "LIST_REF" value from the same row selected inserted into the second table "customer_reference" at the same time in into its own field.

I think i am missing a loop or something i just cant seem to figure this out! And  after hours of searching i just cant seem to find the answer!

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated here is my code.

```
<form action="request_STEP2-test4.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="autoSumForm" id="customer_upload" form="form" />
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_list");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql)) {
    $select = '<select name="NAME">  echo  value =  "Select"';
    while ($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $select .= '<option value="'.$rs['IDCUST'].'&nbsp - &nbsp'.$rs['NAME']. '     '.$rs['LIST_REF']. $ps['LIST_REF'].' ">'.$rs['IDCUST'].'&nbsp - &nbsp'.$rs['NAME']. $rs['LIST_REF']. '</option>' ;
    }
}

$select .= '</select>';

echo $select;
?>

<input type="submit" class="report_button" value="Add Customer" />

</form>

<?php

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) die('Could not connect:' .mysql_error());

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) die ('Can\t use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error ());

$value = $_POST['customer_reference'];
$value2 = $_POST['NAME'];
$value3 = $_POST['LIST_REF'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO customer_results ( 
        customer_reference,
        customer_name,
        PRICE_LIST
        )
    VALUES (
        '$value',
        '$value2',
        '$value3'
        )";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

P.S i am aware injections and PDO.

UPDATE!!!!!!!!!!!
FOUND THE SOLUTION HERE: [Show multiple values from a row when dropdown box is used from mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870094/show-multiple-values-from-a-row-when-dropdown-box-is-used-from-mysql-database)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that `&nbsp;` inside an input's `value` attribute will be literally `'&nbsp;'`, not a space character. Also, your whole model seems flawed. In your `customer_results` table you should ONLY list the ID of the customer, not the ID and name concatenated together. That's a recipe for disaster right there. Also, you really need to be using PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements and bound parameters to prevent SQL injection attacks. "Being aware" of something doesn't keep you safe from it and it is no more difficult to do than what you have there.

Comment: Also as a deleted answer says, you have `$ps` instead of `$rs` a couple of times.

Comment: This also looks weird. Not sure if this is what you really want, especially since it's invalid HTML: `$select= '<select name="NAME">  echo  value =  "Select"';`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Mike! All the points that you made work fine (Besides the PDO which i will correct shortly) The '&nbsp;' gives a space perfectly. My main concern is getting the $rs['LIST_REF'] value to be inserted into the $value3 = $_POST['LIST_REF']; area. Any Ideas?

Comment: As a side note: I have just tested the $ps instead of $rs and have corrected that.

Comment: I have tried $value3 = $rs['LIST_REF']; but it doesn't work

Comment: The value of each option should just be the customer's ID. You can then use it to join to the customer table to get any column value in that table.

Comment: i add the this:    $lr= $select['LIST_REF'];   and changed value 3 to: $value3 = $lr; however now it inserts a "<" into the database...no idea why!?